# Nennen Sie mich

Tags: accusative, person-names

Ihr könnt mich einen Dummkopf nennen (das dann auf jeden Fall mit Akkusativ), aber wie heißt es?

> Nennen Sie mich Herrn Meier.
>
> Nennen Sie mich Herr Meier.
>
> Nennen Sie mich "Herr Meier".

Variante 1 tut mir ehrlich gesagt in den Ohren weh.

Comment: Ich bin mir auf Anhieb auch nicht sicher, wie das heißen muss. Aber das liegt vielleicht auch daran, dass ich das nie so sagen würde: Entweder "Mein Name ist/Ich heiße Herr Meier", oder "Nennen Sie mich X", wobei X ein alternativer Name oder der Vorname ist (wobei es dann eher wäre "Nenn mich X"), und dann stellt sich diese Frage einfach nicht. Aber die Frage an sich, sehr interessant ;)

Comment: "Nennen Sie mich Herr Meier." Variante 1 bedeutet, dass man *dem* Herrn Meier genannt werden soll (so a la "ihm bekannt gemacht"). Variante 3 lassen wir mal ganz außer Acht, denn das verlangt vom Angesprochenen unmögliches, oder soll der jedesmal die Gänsefüßchen mit den Fingern anzeigen, wenn er/sie Herrn Meier anspricht? :)

Comment: @OregonGhost Ja - aber die Frage ist eigentlich unabhängig vom hier verwendeten "Herr Meier". Da könnte auch "Alfred" oder sonstwas stehen, die Frage bleibt gleich, und in jenen lockereren anderen Varianten ist das durchaus im Gebrauch, würde ich sagen.

Comment: @OregonGhost OK, vielleicht habe ich mal wieder zu sehr vom Originaltext, um den es geht abstrahiert. Näher dran wäre "Jemand - **nennen wir in Herr(n) Meier** - macht dies und das"

Comment: @Mörre: Nein, die Frage bleibt nicht genau gleich, denn bei einem Vornamen stellt sich die Frage nicht, ob man ein *n* anhängt oder nicht ;) Warum schreibst du deinen ersten Kommentar nicht als Antwort?

Comment: @OregonGhost Weil ich nur verständlich volkstümlich schreiben und reden kann - nach dem Lesen der Antwort hier werde ich nur noch Englisch reden, denn ganz eindeutig kann ich kein Deutsch ;-) *(kein Missverständnis bitte - I love that answer)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also, der Duden schreibt zum Verb *nennen*, dass es

> im Aktiv ein Aukkusativobjekt und ein Objektprädikativ im Akkustiv

verlangt. Im Beispielsatz ist das Akkusativobjekt *mich* und der Objektprädikativ ist der Name (egal welcher). 
Zum Thema Nomenflektion stellt der Duden fest, dass es eine Tendenz gibt, im Akkusativ nicht zu flektieren so kein Artikel vorangeht. Zwar  heißt es auch, dass *Herr* dazu eine Ausnahme bildet und meist flektiert wird. Allerdings nicht immer.
Wie @Mörre in einem Kommentar festgestellt hat, hat ein flektiertes *Herrn* eine andere Bedeutung. Es wird dann nämlich als Dativ verstanden.

Daher würde ich sagen:

Es handelt sich um einen unflektierten Akkusativ.

(Quelle: "Die Grammatik" Duden, 8. Auflage)